# Get TextBox value from Splunk token

Tags: javascript, splunk

I do not fully understand Splunks token system. I have the most basic of search form. I want to just use the text and on submit send the text to a PHP file(ajax call) and send a call out to my API that will return data to display in 
"display_info".

```
<div class="dashboard-body container-fluid main-section-body" data-role="main">
<div class="dashboard-header clearfix">
    <h2>Whois Lookup HTML</h2>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
    <div class="input input-text" id="input1">
        <label>Domain</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-submit" id="search_btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="display_info"></div>
```

So on submit the

```
submittedTokenModel
```

is set with the value from the textbox.And then the submitToken function fires.

```
  function submitTokens() {
        // Copy the contents of the defaultTokenModel to the submittedTokenModel and urlTokenModel
        FormUtils.submitForm({ replaceState: pageLoading });

//Grab textbox value and run AJAX to PHP function
        console.log(submittedTokenModel); 
//      var tv = submittedTokenModel.get("");
//      var tv = tokens.get("");
//     console.log(tv); 
    }
```

I do not understand how to access the text value from the submittedTokenModel. The documentation to me doesn't really seem to be helping me on this

Answer (score 0):

*(I'd put this in a comment but I can't because <50)*

I believe that your line `var tv = submittedTokenModel.get("");`
 [should work for accessing the text of your token](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/444027/how-to-get-the-token-value-inside-my-javascript-co.html) if you put the token name inside the quotes. Not sure if you already tried that, but it appears to be the way to do it in JS.

`var tv = submittedTokenModel.get("token_name");`

Note that I am very new to this system myself, so I could be wrong about all of this, and I might be misunderstanding your question. Please feel free to clarify and I'll revise.

Comment: Yeah it was the way to get the data from the token. But Splunk doesnt support PHP. So I have to change it, so it now on submit it sends the token to a python script somehow lol